# Restrict developers to pull production environment of AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-js

We are creating the backend of our mobile/web app in Amplify and we have two environments there

1- Amplify Prod
2- Amplify Dev

Currently all of our developers who have access to amplify can pull both dev and prod environment in their local systems by running the amplify pull command. What we are trying to figure out is that is there any way we can restrict them to pull the prod environment? Like when they try to pull the prod environment they need to provide a password for successful pull or just totally restrict them to pull the prod? TIA

Comment: Were you ever able to find an answer to this question? If not, do you want to ask it on the GitHub repo for Amplify and see what they say? I'm currently facing a similar issue.